# Python OSerror [Winerror 126]

Tags: python

Trying to `import usb1` from libusb1 1.7 and it gives me this error:

```
OSerror [Winerror 126]
```

Relatively new to Python. I have tried installing some DLLs but it didn't help. Tried installing Windows Visual C++ also didn't help.

Python version is 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

before importing any library / package make sure that those are installed.
use:

```
pip install libusb1
```

refer below link for installation of packages

[https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/][1]

This is because a runtime dependency of one of the DLLs (`libzbar-64.dll` or `libiconv.dll` on a 64-bit build of Python; `libzbar-32.dll` or `libiconv-2.dll` on a 32-bit build) was not found.

try this https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: Thanks for replying! yes the packages were installed.